# Screen go blank with WIFI USB Dongle

Tags: python, linux, c++

Im already finish my Raspbian OS installation using sdcard write. not NOOBs and be able to use the raspberry pi without any problem. but, when i shutdown and insert the USB wireless dongle and turn back on. the screen go blank. when i take out the USB wireless dongle and turn the raspberry pi on it come back to normal.

what happen?? i want to connect my raspberry pi to internet via wireless connection but it seem my raspberry pi got issues with the USB adapter

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your power supply is not powerful enough. Wireless dongles may draw enough current to cause this kind of problems. Use a USB charger that can provide at least 2 Amps. A thicker and shorter cable could also help because this would decrease the voltage drop of the cable.

Comment: The power supply is my first guess as well. You can try connecting the wifi dongle to a *separately powered* USB hub. Which Pi do you have? - some of the Pi:s may have trouble supplying enough current through the USB ports, even when the power supply is powerful enough.